# EBay API Call Get Seller Transactions not Returning Seller Feedback Rating

Tags: java, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm using the `GetSellerTransactionsCall` from `eBay Trading API` to obtain transaction from an eBay Seller.

According to [eBay Documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerTransactions.html#Response.Seller.FeedbackPrivate) this call is suppose to return a `Seller` object which contains a `UserType` with the following data:

[Seller Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysmgr.png)

[User Type with Feedback Star Rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kETGI.png)

I'm using the code below to execute `Get Seller Transactions Call`:

```
GetSellerTransactionsCall getSellerTransactionsCall = new GetSellerTransactionsCall();
getSellerTransactionsCall.setApiContext(ebayAPI.getAPIContext(profileID));
DetailLevelCodeType[] detailsLevels = new DetailLevelCodeType[1];
detailsLevels[0] = DetailLevelCodeType.RETURN_ALL;
    
getSellerTransactionsCall.setDetailLevel(detailsLevels);
    
getSellerTransactionsCall.setIncludeFinalValueFee(true);


TransactionType[] transactionTypes = getSellerTransactionsCall.getSellerTransactions();


UserType sellerAsUserType = getSellerTransactionsCall.getSeller();
System.out.println("Seller: " +sellerAsUserType ); // Prints null
FeedbackRatingStarCodeType feedbackRatingStarCodeType = sellerAsUserType.getFeedbackRatingStar();
System.out.println("Feedback Rating Star Code: " + feedbackRatingStarCodeType); // Prints null
```

I know the call itself is successful as I am able to iterate through all transactions of the given seller - so this is not a question of whether the call was successful or not.

Why are  `sellerAsUserType` and `feedbackRatingStarCodeType` both null?

Comment: From my experience, EBay's API is hit or miss. Don't expect their API to work the way the say it does.